# How do I create a file in the Downloads folder on android?

Tags: java, android, file

I am trying to download a file from an FTP server and save it to a file in the Downloads folder. In the emulator (since there is an AndroidAPI 30) it gives a Permission Denied, apparently because

```
getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

is outdated. How else can I save the file to the Downloads folder?
Here is the code to create the file:

```
public void downloadFile() {
        String filename = this.filename;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename);
                try {
                    OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                    client.connect("backup-storage5.hostiman.ru");
                    client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    client.login("*********", "********");
                    client.retrieveFile("/" + filename, outputStream);
                    client.logout();
                    client.disconnect();
                    System.out.println("ALL GOOD!");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("FAILED TO DOWNLOAD FILE FROM SERVER!{n" + e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: You can create files in Download folder with the usual WRITE permission. On Android 10 devices requestLegacyExternalStorage="true". Your code looks ok.

Comment: Yes, I have this permission, but for some reason it still throws an exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/800px-University_of_Manchester_Atlas,_January_1963.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: Try on more emulators. Try on devices. Tell of all the Android version.